# javascript, disappearing reappearing text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new at this and I need all the help I can get. These paragraphs are supposed to disappear when each of the boxes are checked.  What am I doing wrong here?

Javascript

```
function showPara() {
    document.getElementById("first").style.visibility=(document.formex.firstpara.checked) ? "visible" : "hidden";
    document.getElementById("second").style.visibility=(document.formex.secondpara.checked) ? "visible" : "hidden";
    document.getElementById("third").style.visibility=(document.formex.thirdpara.checked) ? "visible" : "hidden";
return true;        
}
```

HTML

```
<p id="first">This is the first paragraph</p>
<p id="second">This is the second paragraph</p>
<p id="third">This is the third paragraph</p>
<form name="formex">
<input type="checkbox" name="firstpara" onClick="showPara();" />First Paragraph<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="secondpara" onClick="showPara();" />Second Paragraph<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="thirdpara" onClick="showPara();" />Third Paragraph<br />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And your form should be closed...

Comment: @codehorse: `visibility = 'visibility'`?

Comment: @codehorse think the tag is right. style.visibility takes 'visible/hidden'

Comment: @codehorse No, that's the value, not the property

Comment: Your code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/mbrCh/ (even with the missing `</form>` tag).

Comment: It sounds like you want to set `visibility: hidden` when checked? So change the `.checked) ? "visible" : "hidden";` to `.checked) ? "hidden" : "visible";`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to inverse the position of "visible" and "hidden" so that it reads

```
? "hidden" : "visible";
```

And if you want the paragraphs hidden by default you must run the function on body onload as well. Alternatively you can remove the checked attribute from the checkboxes if the paragraphs should be visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/7U36x/5/

Answer (score 1):

One enhancement that will make this task less difficult is changing the `name` of the `input` to match the `id` of the `p`.  You can see this change in the supplied HTML.  Also notice `this` is passed to the inline function attached to each `input`.

Once this markup change is made, the Javascript becomes less verbose. You can simply select the element using the `name` attribute, then toggle the visibility appropriately given the value of `checked`.

**Javascript**

```
function showPara(e)
 {
        document.getElementById(e.getAttribute("name")).style.visibility= ((e.checked) ? "hidden" : "visible");
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="first">This is the first paragraph</p>
  <p id="second">This is the second paragraph</p>
  <p id="third">This is the third paragraph</p>
  <form name="formex">
  <input type="checkbox" name="first" onClick="showPara(this);" />First Paragraph<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="second" onClick="showPara(this);" />Second Paragraph<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="third" onClick="showPara(this);" />Third Paragraph<br />
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/U5w2q/1/

Answer (score 0):

Working showPara() function:

```
function showPara() {
    document.getElementById("first").style.visibility=(document.forms.formex.firstpara.checked ? "visible" : "hidden");
    document.getElementById("second").style.visibility=(document.forms.formex.secondpara.checked ? "visible" : "hidden");
    document.getElementById("third").style.visibility=(document.forms.formex.thirdpara.checked ? "visible" : "hidden");
}
```

The problem was that you were accessing the elements as `document.formex.`... instead of `docuement.forms.formex.`...

You also had the closing bracket of the inline if statement in the wrong place.

You should also close the  element too...

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/cjvD4/

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your HTML like below -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="firstpara" onClick="showPara(this, 'first');" />First Paragraph<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="secondpara" onClick="showPara(this, 'second');" />Second Paragraph<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="thirdpara" onClick="showPara(this, 'third');" />Third Paragraph<br />
```

And your javascript fundtion to be like below -

```
function showPara(chkbox, paraid) {
if(chkbox.checked)
    document.getElementById("first").style.visibility == "visible";
else 
    document.getElementById("first").style.visibility == "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p id="first">This is the first paragraph</p>
<p id="second">This is the second paragraph</p>
<p id="third">This is the third paragraph</p>
<form name="formex">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" style="visibility:visible"  name="firstpara" onClick="showPara('first', this);" />First Paragraph<br />
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" style="visibility:visible"   name="secondpara" onClick="showPara('second', this);" />Second Paragraph<br />
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" style="visibility:visible"   name="thirdpara" onClick="showPara('third', this);" />Third Paragraph<br />
</form>
```

```js
<script>
function showPara(id, ck) {
    p = document.getElementById(id)
    if(ck.checked == true){
        p.style.visibility = 'visible'     
    }else{
       p.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }    
  }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XK97j/